# control gestures with kinect,sample code

Tags: kinect, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyone to give me a sample code for controlling gestures using Kinect?I'm trying to control the Nxt-Lego Mindstorms robot, and I can't figure out how to make the Kinect Distinguish the left and the right hand of the person in control(I basically want to link the right hand to the right motor and the left hand to the left motor.I would like to replicate the same thing Mauro Brunato and Xander did(for a video,just type "Kinect based control NXT" in youtube)).The sooner the better,I would like to finish this project by Thursday,please answer today if possible.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9962/control-gestures-with-kinect,sample-code/) by [Cruzio007](https://answers.ros.org/users/537/cruzio007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Haven't tried it myself, but this package might help you.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/hand_interaction

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cruzio007](https://answers.ros.org/users/537/cruzio007/) on 2011-05-16**:
Thank you man,I was already working with it.I gonna continue with it then.Thanks